# returnValue not changing on spyOn mock service jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test a component that uses a service, this service has a function that returns a boolean. Based on this boolean, my component can change its template.

For some reason, returnValue within each test isn't overriding the returnValue to what I need so the template can actually change and be tested.

Here's my test:

```
describe("LikeButtonComponent", () => {
    let component: LikeButtonComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LikeButtonComponent>;
    const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj("UserService", {
        isLiked$: of(true),
        getPostId$: of("12983"),
        likePost: () => {},
        unlikePost: () => {}
    });

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [LikeButtonComponent]
        })
            .overrideComponent(LikeButtonComponent, {
                set: { providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: mockService }] }
            })
            .compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LikeButtonComponent);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
                fixture.detectChanges();
            });
    }));

    it("should render component", () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should call like", () => {
        component.likePost();

        expect(mockService.likePost).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it("should call unlike", () => {
        component.unlikePost();

        expect(mockService.unlikePost).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it("should have 'liked' class when isLiked is true", () => {
        mockService.isLiked$.and.returnValue(of(true));
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const container = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(".likedButton");
        expect(container.classList.contains("likedButton--active")).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should have 'unliked' class when isLiked is false", () => {
        mockService.isLiked$.and.returnValue(of(false)); // <-- this isn't working as expected.

        fixture.detectChanges();

        const container = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(".unlikedButton");
        expect(container.classList.contains("unlikedButton--active")).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

There seems to be some desync issue. Attempted using `fakeAsync` or `async`, but didn't solve it. It's always taking the main spyCreate values, so if I put it to return Observable.of(false), it will remain there and no matter how I want to change it later on within the individual tests cases, it won't work or the component can't update properly so I can check the classes applied.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that we are hardcoding `isLiked$` to true here:

```
const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj("UserService", {
        isLiked$: of(true),
        getPostId$: of("12983"),
        likePost: () => {},
        unlikePost: () => {}
    });
```

To get around this issue, I would use a BehaviorSubject.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
....
describe("LikeButtonComponent", () => {
    let component: LikeButtonComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LikeButtonComponent>;
    // add this line
    const isLikedBehaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
    const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj("UserService", {
        // link isLiked$ to that BehaviorSubject
        isLiked$: isLikedBehaviorSubject$.asObservable(),
        getPostId$: of("12983"),
        likePost: () => {},
        unlikePost: () => {}
    });
  ....
   it("should have 'unliked' class when isLiked is false", () => {
        // change the BehaviorSubject to false
        isLikedBehaviorSubject$.next(false);

        fixture.detectChanges();

        const container = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(".unlikedButton");
        expect(container.classList.contains("unlikedButton--active")).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Using a BehaviorSubject we can change the value of `isLiked$` dynamically. Before it was `of(true)` always. I don't think you can do `mockService.isLiked$.and.returnValue(of(false));` on an instance variable (which I assume this is an instance variable). You can only do that on a public method.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Although im not sure why im getting this error: ` TypeError: You provided '() => Object(rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["of"])("12983")' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
      at <Jasmine>`. This function that im trying to mock returns an Observable.

Comment: Try adding `.asObservable()`, I have edited my post.

Comment: Nice, yes that one seems to work but the one that is failing is the other method. I need to check what's going on. I will let you know in a few minutes :)

Comment: Found the error on the other function! thanks! you're the man :)